# Integrity error, Not null constant restrained when creating a new game instance

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a web app that allows you to track Spikeball games in a blog like style.

I've tried setting the author of each game to be the current user then delegating with super to save the form when it's submitted but I'm still getting:

> IntegrityError at /game/new/
>   NOT NULL constraint failed: spike_stats_game.creator_id

Here's my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Game(models.Model):
    game = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True,null=True)
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None, blank=True,null=True)
    date_played = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,null=True)
    player2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,null=True)
    player3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,null=True)
    player4 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.game
```

Here's my Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, 
    DetailView, 
    CreateView
)
from .models import Game


def home(request):

    context = {
        'games': Game.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'spike_stats/home.html', context)


class GameListView(ListView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'spike_stats/home.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'games'
    ordering = ['-date_played'] # minus sign orders from newest to oldest


class GameDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Game


class GameCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Game
    fields = ['game', 'score', 'winner', 
    'player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'spike_stats/about.html',
                  {'game': 'Game 1 about'})
```

Even with this fixed, I should still be getting a url error but I can't get past this roadblock. Apologies if any formatting/information or anything is wrong, I'm fairly new to Python and Stack Overflow in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `creator` value but it looks like you're trying to define `author`.

To do this in a `form_valid` do;

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    game = form.save(commit=False)
    game.creator =  self.request.user
    game.save()
    # redirect or whatever you need to do
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed and a LoginRequiredMixin fixed the issue. Thanks!